# How to modify config.v2.json file to run a Docker container with a specific command line parameter?

Tags: docker, synology

I created a docker container in my Synology web user interface. The container shall be run with
`--pull=always` command line parameter, but there is no textbox in the Synology Docker UI where I can specify this parameter.

So I ssh-ed to the Synology, and found the configuration file for the corresponding container, the file is called `config.v2.json`. How exactly can I modify this file, so that the container is run like it would run with "--pull=always" parameter?

Or how else can I force the synology to pull the latest image every time when the container is run? Thank you.
I googled, but found no way how can I add this parameter into the `config.v2.json` file. Maybe it is not possible at all?

Comment: Share that file